# Loop that adds a new excel sheet for each time button is clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add a new excel for each time a button is clicked, since the sheet is named after the date. However, I get an error that says "Cannot rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet, a referenced object library or a workbook refernced by Visual basic."

```
Dim szTodayDate As String
szTodayDate = Format(Date, "mm.dd")
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = szTodayDate
```

What I want is to create a new worksheet that will be named mm.dd.i. While i refers to the number of time I create a new worksheet using the button. Sorry, I'm a VBA newbie.

Thank you for the answers. Gary's Student Made the most efficient one. Solved.

Comment: When I run your code on my side, it works exactly as you describe it should work. Maybe you are trying to run the code many times on the same day without previously deleting the created sheet for that day?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to create a new sheet the same day and will ergo change the name of the worksheet as something like mm.dd.i. Referring to i as the number of times it was made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub sjvyv()
    Dim szTodayDate As String
    szTodayDate = Format(Date, "mm.dd")
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    ReDim N(1 To Sheets.Count)

    i = 1
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If Left(ws.Name, 5) = szTodayDate Then
            N(i) = Mid(wsname, 6)
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next ws

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = szTodayDate & "." & i
End Sub
```

Comment: far more succinct than my own answer - as usual! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that creates a new name for the sheet, that is available:

```
Sub AddSheet()
    Dim TodayDate As String
    Dim i As Integer
    TodayDate = Format(Date, "mm.dd")
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

    i = 1

    Do While Not SheetNameAvailable(TodayDate & "." & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ws.Name = TodayDate & "." & i
End Sub

Function SheetNameAvailable(SheetName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
    SheetNameAvailable = (Err.Number <> 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
On Error Resume Next
Set tempWS = Sheets(szTodayDate)

ws.Name = szTodayDate & IIf(tempWS Is Nothing, "", GetSheetCount(szTodayDate))

Set tempWS = Nothing

On Error GoTo 0
```

---

```
Function GetSheetCount(dateToTest) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 1

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sh.Name Like dateToTest & "*" Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    GetSheetCount = i
End Function


ws.Name = szTodayDate & ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count + 1
```

Just append the count of sheets (+1) to the end.